# Intellij idea: JPA annotations in property instead of getter

Tags: java, jpa, intellij-idea, spring-annotations

Is there a way to make IntelliJ put the auto generated JPA Entity annotations (@Column, @Id, etc) **in the properties themselves**, instead of the getter?

There's an answer that points to a Hub issue that works for xml-based configurations, but there are two follow-up comments (one is mine) asking how to do this with @Configuration (no xml) and there's no answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not at the moment, related issues:

- [IDEA-166294](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-166294) Generates JPA annotations over attributes
- [IDEA-76638](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-76638) JPA: Customize Generate Persistence Mapping
- [IDEA-64709](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-64709) JPA: Provide possibility to choose between Field and Property access when generation jpa with 'Generate Persistence Mapping'

Answer (score 0):

213.2647 will solve this issue, can be download with 2021.3 EAP 1 or later release.
https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2021/09/intellij-idea-2021-3-eap-1/

Original issue:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-64709